# Incompatible version constraints on polymer, with AngularDart

Tags: dart, angular-dart, dart-polymer

I have a Dart project with polymer going and the simple Polymer element fancy_button. I want to add AngularDart so I do so by adding the package to my `pubspec.yaml` so it looks like so:

```
name: woven_sandbox
dependencies:
  browser: any
  polymer: ">=0.10.0 <0.11.0"
  fancy_button: any
  angular: 0.10.0
  shadow_dom: any
transformers:
- angular
- polymer:
    entry_points:
    - web/hello_world.html
```

When I try to `pub get` I get these odd version constraint issues:

```
$ pub get
Resolving dependencies... (6.1s)
Incompatible version constraints on polymer:
- fancy_button 0.0.1 depends on version >=0.9.0+1 <0.9.1
- woven_sandbox 0.0.0 depends on version >=0.10.0 <0.11.0
```

I don't get it.

Answer (score 2):

I have got a similar issue.

**in your first pubspec.yaml**

As say in the error message, fancy_button depend of a specific version of polymer, but you say in your first pubspec.yaml that you want the version 0.10.0 but : 0.10 > 0.9.1.

So in the pubspec.yaml of fancy_button, the condition :

> polymer: ">=0.9.0+1 <0.9.1"

is not true, so it say that a issue occurred.

**in your second pubspec.yaml**

In your second pubspec, you say that you need any version of polymer, so when pub tools will search to get the best match, it will see that fancy_button need the version 0.9.X, and no others package need a differente version so it will download the 0.9 version of the polymer package.

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to resolve things but why?

```
name: woven_sandbox
dependencies:
  angular: any
  angular_node_bind: any
  browser: any
  polymer: any
  shadow_dom: any
transformers:
- polymer:
    entry_points:
    - web/hello_world.html
```